# What is the difference between atomic density and intrinsic concentration?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, conductors, density, electronic-band-theory

If a $\rm Si$ sample is doped with boron impurities in the ratio of $1:10^6$ , it means that for every $10^6$ $\rm Si$ atoms, 1 boron atom is added.

I have been given information that atomic density of $\rm Si$ is $\rm 5×10^22 \ atoms/cm^3$.

Also intrinsic concentration is $\rm 1.5×10^10 \  atoms/cm^3$

To find out the total concentration of boron impurity, have to use the ratio like this :

$1:10^6 =$ boron concentration : atomic density of $\rm Si$.

**My question :**

Why can't intrinsic concentration be used in place of atomic density of $\rm Si$ ? Thought that both denotes the $\rm Si$ atom concentrations.

Comment: The 'intrinsic concentration' is the density of electrons (and holes) in an undoped Si sample. Note that it is much much much less than the hole concentration obtained by doping with $10^{16}$B/cm$^{3}$.

Answer (score -2):

Atomic density represents number of atoms present per unit volume
where as intrinsic carrier density represents number of atoms capable of breaking their bonds(and thus giving rise to free electrons in conduction band) at a specific temperature per unit volume

All the atoms do not break bonds at a specific temperature(under thermal equilibrium) those atoms which are capable of breaking their bonds contribute to intrinsic carrier concentration
so intrinsic carrier concentration <= Atomic density

Comment: PAVAN, All CAPS is bad formating, and often interpreted as yelling. Please avoid using this style.